# How to create a piece of C#.NET script to let MySql server execute a MySql Script?

Tags: c#, mysql, scripting, execute

Suppose I have a myTest.sql scripts, which contains thousands of "create table blahblah" statements.

myTest.sql :

```
 CREATE TABLE A;
 CREATE TABLE A1;
 ....
 CREATE TABLE A1000;
```

What Im trying to achieve is that make an C# script to force MySql server EXECUTE the myTest.sql file, instead of doing

```
  using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConectionString))
  {
    MySqlCommand newCmd = new MySqlCommand("create statement here 1", cn);
    cn.Open();
    newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
  }
```

I dont want to repeat 1000 times or a for loop something like that. Thanks for all helps and please forgive my grammar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you load the myTest.sql file into a string and pass it to the MySqlCommand.

```
string myTestSql = IO.File.ReadAllText("myTest.sql");
...
MySqlCommand newCmd = new MySqlCommand(myTestSql, cn);
```

Should work as long as MySQL accepts commands separated by semicolons.

Comment: Thx Andy ! Which one should I use ? ExecuteNonQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't have to open and close the connection every single time, but it would be the cleanest if you ran each of these one at a time and look at the result to ensure that the statement completed successfully.  Unfortunately if you run a giant statement with 1000 statements and it fails, you don't have an easy way of determining which step(s) were successful and which have to be repeated.

Comment: Thx scwagner ! Thats true .. But right now I dont have a better solution, besides table creatation statements .. I got other hundreds of create stored procedure statements ..

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html)
You can do it using mysql command-line and shell with `System.Process` static methods if you want to use .net / c#.

Comment: Thx Tocco. But I am not sure MySql Command-line is a mandatory install option.. I cant guarantee that every user installed mysql command-line

Comment: I shouldn't know that is a Client application. Did you try to use @AndyP approach?

Comment: Not yet .. wondering how to run "newCmd", like calling ExecuteNonQuery or the other..